# How to tell which version of Outlook I've got?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm interested to know if there's a reasonably easy way to determine which version of Outlook I have installed on my computer.

On the version I've got, there's no "About" option under the File menu, or any of the other menus.

Comment: To the downvoter, I'd appreciate if you would please state a reason... the whole reason I created this question, and it's answer, was because the other questions didn't address the same scope, and furthermore didn't have an answer that covered all versions.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a Help option in the menu bar of the window, then click it and choose "About Microsoft Office Outlook" to see your version number. This should work for Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, Outlook Express.

Click the File menu option in the menu bar of the window, and then select either Help (this should exist for Outlook 2010) or Office Account (this should exist for Outlook 2013 and 2016). There may be an "About Outlook" button to click for exact version details.

Comment: 1 of 2 Thanks. When I installed WIN11, at first I seemed able to only access a cut down version of  OLK email that was little better than the browser app. I then found another version that seemed similar to Office Outlook, in Program Files (or in the ...(86x) folder), that seemed much better, but with the modern blue logo. I'm now using O365 and so far the OLK still seems fairly similar to the old Office Outlook - but all the notices on Office Watch suggest that MS will replace it with an oversimplified version soon. Does anyone think I can avoid a cut down version in the future?

Comment: 2 of 2 AFAIK, the current Office Outlook will stop being supported fairly soon, so that wouldn't be a lasting solution. Will I be left with my last O365 version if I then kill my subscription?